# xfce crashes/logs out (lubuntu)

Tags: lubuntu, xfce

I have been using lubuntu for a couple of years now. In the last couple of months a new kind of problem has surfaced:

Xfce seems to crash - I suddenly get a black screen with some text about linux services starting (it flashes past - I'll try to note down what it says next time it happens), and after some seconds I end up at the login screen, where I can log in without problems, start up all my applications etc.

This always seems to happen while I an moving a window with the mouse on the desktop. I have especially noted it while running mupdf in a secondary workspace, moving it between screens, but it has also happened when I moved a firefox window in a non-dramatic fashion.

I use the laptop's screen together with two monitors, and set up those using arandr for a three screen wide workspace.

Any ideas what's going on here? Are there some log files or something that I could look at?

Comment: Same issue here (lubuntu 16.04). Any luck with this? I use xrandr for a multi-monitor config as well.

Comment: Not really. I stopped using mupdf and avoid using the secondary workspace. :(